# Can I specify that multiple generics in a method parameter must be the same type using "<? extends Type>"?

Tags: java, generics, parameters

Suppose I have a method, such as

```
protected static List<? extends ObjectWithNameAndId> combineSelectedWithFilteredList(
    String[] selectedRecordIds,
    List<? extends ObjectWithNameAndId> previousList,
    List<? extends ObjectWithNameAndId> newFilteredList) {
```

Is there a way I can specify that the generics type of `previousList`, `newFilteredList`, and the return type must be the same? For example:

```
protected static List<K extends ObjectWithNameAndId> combineSelectedWithFilteredList(
    String[] selectedRecordIds,
    List<K extends ObjectWithNameAndId> previousList,
    List<K extends ObjectWithNameAndId> newFilteredList) {
```

Thus you could pass in two `List<Foo>`, but not one `List<Foo>` and one `List<Bar>` even if `Foo` and `Bar` both extend/implement `ObjectWithNameAndId`. And if you passed in two `List<Foo>`, even not knowing the implementation, you could count on getting a `List<Foo>` back out, not just a List full of any types which extend/implement `ObjectWithNameAndId`.

Comment: You say "map" but your code (and later you again) say "list".

Comment: @Makoto Fixed. It was originally `Map<String, ? extends ObjectWithNameAndId>`, but I wanted to simplify things a bit for the question, and missed a couple spots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to declare the type parameter first:

```
protected static <K extends ObjectWithNameAnd> List<K> combineSelectedWithFilteredList(
    String[] selectedRecordIds,
    List<K> previousList,
    List<K> newFilteredList) {}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html for complete details and more examples.

BONUS:

If you want to specify more than one generic type for a method, it would look something like this:

```
public static <K extends ObjectWithName, C extends Collection<K>> C 
    truncateObjectNamesInCollection(C collection, int maxNameLength) {
```

The above example could take in a `List<Type>` and it would return `List<Type>`, or a `Set<ObjectWithNameAndId>` and it would return `Set<ObjectWithNameAndId>`

Comment: Wow! I was honestly expecting a "No and here's why" answer. Thanks!